# ios Universal Links - from multiple domains

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have a question about the apple-app-site-association and where it should be deployed in the case where I have 2 (or more) websites that are going to display a URL that will direct a user to my app.

For instance, I have a main website where my AASA file is deployed here:
www.my-main-domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

With a wildcard in it like this:
"paths": ["/my-app/*"]

This means any link like this:
www.my-main-domain.com/my-app

Will open up in my app.

What if I have another website and I want to link to the app from there.  The new site is:
www.my-other-domain.com

Can I link to the app using the same URL above?  Do I need another AASA file deployed on the new domain?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is no need to make changes on this other site, I was given incorrect information.   There was an issue with the way it was implemented in our app that was causing it to not work from other domains.